# Exporting dataframe to csv with read.format() fails with java.lang.NullPointer exception

Tags: scala, csv, dataframe, apache-spark

Below is the code that I am executing:

```
val df = sc.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("C:\\Users\\Tsingha\\Desktop\\Head.csv")
//print the data frame
df.show(false)

//This line is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException 
df.write.csv("data1.csv")
```

Comment: can you edit your question to add the full stacktrace ?

Comment: maybe you spark core version is different than spark sql ?

Comment: Please add stacktrace. By the way, the argument which is given to write.csv(...) is the directory name, not the file name. So in this example, you will get /foo/bar/data1.csv/part-00000-XXXXXXXXXX.csv